# Access 2013: Trying to get a SubForm to refresh after Name is chosen in Main Form

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have a  Main Form with a Subform within it. The Main Form [Test] is just a drop down of names. I want the Subform to pull up the addresses associated with the name that is chosen. I have tried the following:

On the Drop Down on "After Update"

```
Me.Address_DatasheetSub1.Form.Refresh
Me.Address_DatasheetSub1.Form.Requery
Forms![Test].[Address_DatasheetSub1].Form.Refresh
Forms![Test].[Address_DatasheetSub1].Form.Requery
```

I have also tried on separate button "On Click"

```
Me.Address_DatasheetSub1.Form.Refresh
Me.Address_DatasheetSub1.Form.Requery
Forms![Test].[Address_DatasheetSub1].Form.Refresh
Forms![Test].[Address_DatasheetSub1].Form.Requery
```

Nothing seems to work. However if I am on the Form View and press the "Refresh All" button on the Access ribbon, it works.

Comment: Why not use Link Master Field and Link Child Field?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the LinkMasterFields and LinkChildFields properties of the subform control.

- Set LinkMasterFields to: NameOfYourCombobox
- Set LinkChildFields to: NameOfTheFieldYouFilterOn

and remove all code regarding the requery.

Comment: I have that done already, from what I have been reading, it should work, but it just doesn't seem to.

Comment: Then something else is going on.